# Is it possible to make aws sam local run faster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I've tried `sam local start-api` on both CDK and SAM applications and I notice the same behaviour on both. Having a Lambda function that does nothing, literally this is the code:

```js
export async function handler(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
        body: `Hello, CDK! You've hit ${event.path}\n`
    }
}
```

it seems to always take more than 4 seconds to run, often around 6 seconds. Such a function should be in the milliseconds. But the way sam local is doing it seems to be creating a Docker container each time.

The logs show this:

```
Mounting C:\Users\pupeno\Code\example4-be\lambda as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: d63b417e-460e-4861-a2f1-85ebb29472a4 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: d63b417e-460e-4861-a2f1-85ebb29472a4
REPORT RequestId: d63b417e-460e-4861-a2f1-85ebb29472a4  Init Duration: 0.32 ms  Duration: 140.76 ms     Billed Duration: 141 ms Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 128 MB
2022-01-21 22:40:29 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2022 22:40:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It spents the vast majority of the time on the first line and indeed the actual function took 140ms.

Is there a way to speed this up, to be at similar speeds with Ruby on Rails, Django, NodeJS + Express, etc?

Comment: The sam-local is intended as a DEV tool and is not really designed to keep running fast. Maybe you could enforce `EAGER` warm parameter (see docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html)

Comment: I know it's intended for development, but so is Ruby on Rails, Django, Express when run locally and they are faster _when_ loading code, and much faster when not loading code.

Comment: That parameter is interesting actually, I'll do some experiments.

Comment: Running lambda (any serverless) has a quite complex infrastructure around, it is not just running the code itself, so the startup time is longer. Indeed the question is how to stick the startup time only at the startup

Comment: Using `EAGER` shaved one second in some of the cases and didn't make a difference in others. I guess that's pretty much what's expected of that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and sometimes the Mounting just gets stuck. I am using Windows Subsystem For Linux (WSL) and Docker Desktop for running the containers locally. Cleaning up unused and dangling containers from Docker Desktop seems to help to speed up the Mounting. Not a proper solution, but might help.